# Is literary symbolism blasphemy?

Tags: symbolism, cs-lewis, blasphemy

C.S. Lewis is widely known to have been a devout Christian.   In Narnia, the lion Aslan seems to symbolize Jesus.  He is executed in the first book in a manner not entirely unlike crucifixion and rises from the dead, for example.  Another character by another author is Franklin, in J.D. Salinger's "Just Before the War with the Eskimos."  He injures his feet and hands and is also considered by many to be a reference to Jesus.

These are of course just two of many, many times when authors have given a character qualities that symbolize Jesus, or when a major plot point is reminiscent of crucifixion.  These symbols have me wondering, though, isn't it some sort of blasphemy?

In the first case, Aslan is a powerful and noble hero who works miracles.  Could writing this book be akin to worshiping a false idol?  In the second, Franklin is unkind and has many vices.  He seems rather a poor choice for a Christ symbol.

**Under what conditions is it actually appropriate from a religious standpoint to create a Christ figure?**

EDIT: I see a downvote wondering what definition of blasphemy I have in mind.  My source is [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blasphemy):

> **blasphemy**
>
> 1. The act of insulting or showing contempt or lack of reverence for God.
> 2. The act of claiming the attributes of a deity.

C.S. Lewis fits definition 2, where a character he imagines claims the attributes of Jesus.  Salinger fits definition 1, for the lack of reverence especially.

Comment: What definition of "blasphemy" are you thinking of that means that clearly fictional characters are included?

Comment: @curiousdannii I added a definition

Comment: *Every* "hero" (using the literary definition) is an image of Christ; the [Hero's Journey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero%27s_journey) is in some senses an echo of Christ's story. Some stories are more blatant about it than others, but... Consider also that God Himself prefigures Christ when he kills an animal to clothe Adam and Eve, and every Hebrew sacrifice — *commanded by God* — is likewise a prefiguring of Christ.

Comment: "where a character he imagines claims the attributes of Jesus" I think you are going need to back up your claim that CS Lewis intended his character to "claim" the attributes of divinity in the sense the definition implies that is that Lewis intended Aslan not to represent Christ but to be Christ (or be God in place of Christ)

Comment: Nuggethead, since you're basically asking is X a sin,  you should define blasphemy according to the moral framework (assuming blasphemy fits in the moral framework) of a faith tradition that is relevant to you (i.e. Calvinism, Catholic, Orthodox etc... ).  There are some Christians who certainly consider it blasphemy (the same way Muslims would) and some who don't, obviously C.S. Lewis didn't.

Comment: @eques, "'Are -are you [in our world] too, Sir?' said Edmund. 'I am,' said Aslan. 'But there I have another name. You must learn to know me by that name. This was the very reason why you were brought to Narnia, that by knowing me here for a little, you may know me better there.'” Intent, nothing; Lewis has Aslan *explicitly claim* to be Christ.

Comment: @Matthew I am familiar -- the key point was "in the sense the definition implies". While it's fairly obvious Lewis intended Aslan to be Christ. It's not clear that he meant it the way the OP intends to understand blasphemy. i.e. did Lewis create Aslan with the intention that people would worship Aslan instead of Christ? If so, that would be blasphemy.

Answer (score 5):

**Is literary symbolism blasphemy?**

The short answer is **no**.

A **Christ figure** is a legitimate manner of expression, as long as the author makes no claim that the literary figure is indeed Christ in person, but remains simply a literary styled symbol only.

Literary imagery must never be thought as being reality, but figurative and symbolic only.

Christ is symbolized in a manner of speaking in various ways, including the Old Testament. Christ is symbolized in the [Paschal Lamb](https://www.gotquestions.org/Passover-Lamb.html).

For some the Brazen Serpent lifted up by Moses in the wilderness symbolized Christ. [Is it true that the Brazen Serpent lifted up by Moses in the wilderness symbolized Christ? Why would the image of a serpent be used to represent the Savior?](https://basic.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1983/09/i-have-a-question/is-it-true-that-the-brazen-serpent-lifted-up-by-moses-in-the-wilderness-symbolized-christ?lang=eng)

We should also note that C.S. Lewis never claims that Aslan symbolizes Christ. Yet the connection between the two can be easily understood by many of the C.S. Lewis readers and fans.

Christ figures are common in literary circles, but none claim these personages are Christ. Take Tolkien’s ***The Lord of the Rings***:

> [**Christ figures**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themes_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings)
>
> The philosopher Peter Kreeft, like Tolkien a Roman Catholic, observes that there is no one complete, concrete, visible Christ figure in *The Lord of the Rings* comparable to **Aslan** in C. S. Lewis's Chronicles of Narnia series. However, Kreeft and Jean Chausse have identified reflections of the figure of Jesus Christ in three protagonists of The Lord of the Rings: Gandalf, Frodo and Aragorn. While Chausse found "facets of the personality of Jesus" in them, Kreeft wrote that "they exemplify the Old Testament threefold Messianic symbolism of prophet (Gandalf), priest (Frodo), and king (Aragorn)".
>
> Several commentators have seen Gandalf's passage through the Mines of Moria, dying to save his companions and returning as "Gandalf the White", as a symbol of the resurrection of Christ. Like Jesus who carried his cross for the sins of mankind, Frodo carried a burden of evil on behalf of the whole world. Frodo walks his "Via Dolorosa" to Mount Doom just like Jesus who made his way to Golgotha. As Frodo approaches the Cracks of Doom, the Ring becomes a crushing weight, just as the cross was for Jesus. Sam Gamgee, Frodo's servant, who carries Frodo up to Mount Doom, parallels Simon of Cyrene, who helps Jesus by carrying his cross to Golgotha. When Frodo accomplishes his mission, like Christ, he says "it is done". Just as Christ ascends to heaven, Frodo's life in Middle-earth comes to an end when he departs to the Undying Lands.

Great Christian authors will force readers to seek out various symbolic meanings within their literary works. C.S. Lewis did a great job in this domain. I can recall reading medieval non-fiction novels that did this very thing and used religious symbolism to affect their expressions of truth of God’s and evil.

Comment: "We should also note that C.S. Lewis never claims that Aslan symbolizes Christ"... except he sort-of does. "'Are -are you [in our world] too, Sir?' said Edmund. 'I am,' said Aslan. 'But there I have another name. You must learn to know me by that name. This was the very reason why you were brought to Narnia, that by knowing me here for a little, you may know me better there.'”